# Need separate credentials for WSE API?

Tags: here-api

When attempting to access the Waypoints Sequence Extensions API, the credentials I use for my trial account fail to authenticate.

These same credentials work on multiple other parts of the API.

Why is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Platform Extensions](https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions) must be specifically whitelisted for your application credentials. These requests take a lot of processing power and because of that they can't be enabled by default as much as I know.
You have to [contact us](https://developer.here.com/contact-us) and request for WSE whitelisting.