# I have registered app_id and app_key giving me this "error"Unauthorized","error_description":"Unauthorized. Th

Tags: here-api

for HERE REST api I have registered app_id and app_key and appended them in url but it is giving me this  "error"Unauthorized","error_description":"Unauthorized. The request is not from an authorized source "

Answer (score 2):

Also, the [FAQs](https://developer.here.com/faqs#access-control) page mentions the following:

> How do I generate an app_id and app_code for my application?
>
> To generate an app_id and app_code for an application, you need to
>   sign in then go to https://developer.here.com/plans to select and
>   register for the appropriate plan.
>
> At the final step in the registration process, an app_id and app_code
>   is automatically generated for your application.
>
> ***Please note, it can take up to an hour for a new app_id to be whitelisted against all services.***

So if you had just created your credentials when you got this error, you may want to try again.

Looking back at the error I received when I attempted to access the API, however, I got the following response:

```
{"details":"invalid credentials for I5zJljd5cZyOx5SyROKT","additionalData":[],"type":"PermissionError","subtype":"InvalidCredentials"}
```

So it may be that Jason's comment above is more appropriate but I'll leave this answer for other users who may come searching after creating new credentials.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to check your credentials would be to make a valid URL call to any of the [REST APIs](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis) - e.g. the Geocoder API: `https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=London&app_id={YO‌​UR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}` - it gives an error response for an invalid pair.

As mentioned in the answer : [Need separate credentials for WSE API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966310/need-separate-credentials-for-wse-api) - you may need to request additional access for the HERE [Platform extensions](https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

selfservesupport@here.com here is the support. Describe ur problem and attach an snapshot where you get error at what request. (URL)